# Postgres, Need help updating only NULL values

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have two tables 'A', 'B'.
I want to write a query that accomplishes the results shown below.

[image]

currently I have this statement

```
UPDATE A
SET version = (
   SELECT B.version
   FROM B 
   WHERE B.id = A.id 
)
```

It works, but it updates ALL the rows, how can I write it so that only the null values are updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE A
SET version = (
SELECT B.version
FROM B
WHERE B.id = A.id
)
where A.version is null